# Remove blank page at the beginning of document

Tags: titles, white-space

*Edited from original post to provide minimal working example as otherwise the question is useless as pointed out in the comments.

I'm trying to create a simple A4 page document with a figure (a tikz figure if that matters). I don't want a title, I don't want extra pages, I don't want numbering, just my figure.

What I get looks like :

[image]

For the numbering, @leandriis pointed out that `\pagestyle(empty)` should be sufficient, which it is. I still have an extra page I don't want.

I have four files for that document :

1. a preamble
2. a definitions file
3. a main
4. and file for my figure.

Preamble :

```
\documentclass[
    10pt, 
    french, 
    twoside 
    ]{article}

\input{definitions}

\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    pdftoolbar= true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    unicode=true,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    pdffitwindow=false,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    pdfauthor={\author},
    pdfcreator={\creator},
    pdfproducer={TeXstudio},
    ]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{pdftitle = {\mTitle}}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% loads both rotfloat and float packages, rotfloat loads both rotating and float packages
% should not be loaded WITH any of the internally loaded packages

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\usepackage[
a4paper,
landscape,
top=2.5cm, 
bottom=2.5cm, 
inner=2.3cm, 
outer=2.3cm
]{geometry}
```

Main :

```
\input{preambule}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\input{cards}
\end{document}
```

Definitions :

```
\def\mTitle {Hanafuda - table des cartes}
\def \creator {myname}
\def \author{myname}
```

Figure file :

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{month}   = [text width=0.082\textwidth, align=center, font=\bfseries]
        \tikzstyle{flower}  = [text width=0.082\textwidth, align=center, font=\footnotesize]
        \tikzstyle{type}    = [text width=0.082\textwidth, align=center, font=\tiny]

        \node [month] at (0.082*00\textwidth,3) {Janvier};
        \node [flower] at (0.082*00\textwidth,2) {Pin};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0.082*00\textwidth,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.078\textwidth]{placeholder}};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0.082*11\textwidth,-12) {\includegraphics[width=0.078\textwidth]{placeholder}};

        \node [type] at (0.082*11\textwidth,-14.005) {lumière \\ (phénix)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

With that code, you get the document screenshoted above.

If I follow up with the advice provided by @David Carlisle, using the standalone package :

My preamble looks like :

```
\documentclass[
    10pt, 
    french, 
    twoside 
    ]{standalone}

\input{definitions}

\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    pdftoolbar= true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    unicode=true,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    pdffitwindow=false,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    pdfauthor={\author},
    pdfcreator={\creator},
    pdfproducer={TeXstudio},
    ]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{pdftitle = {\mTitle}}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% loads both rotfloat and float packages, rotfloat loads both rotating and float packages
% should not be loaded WITH any of the internally loaded packages

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\usepackage[
a4paper,
landscape,
top=2.5cm, 
bottom=2.5cm, 
inner=2.3cm, 
outer=2.3cm
]{geometry}
```

I get the following error : `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{center}` five times (twice for `\begin{center}` and three times for `\end{center}`), and my document looks like :

[image]

The placeholder image is a 672x1061 pixels image.

There is one package I didn't keep in the minimal working example (`\usepackage{svg}`), because I don't think it's part of the problem, and I know it's a nightmare to make it work.

Comment: To remove the page numbers, use `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Could you please turn your code snippets into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that does not rely on external files that are not available to others. (For images, you can use `example-image`)

Comment: Most likely your image is too large to fit into the page margins. You could decrease teh size of teh image or the margins.

Comment: it is impossible to tell why the blank page is there from the information provided (do you get a warning in the log??)  but possibly you are looking for the `standalone` class which always just outputs a single page, sized to the content provided.

Comment: @leandriis I modified the post so that there is a mwe, thanks for pointing out that it was missing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Somehow the `standalone` class generates errors :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tikzpicture is as height as width. You can see that at the following image:[image: geometry of your tikzpicture]

If your image does not fits, latex creates a new page and if the picture still not works, it will add the image without caring about.

You can see, that the picture is to big, if you turn on the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package. [image: picture is to big]

You can workaround that, by including a standalone and set the height of the picture to the height of the text:

standalone:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{month}   = [text width=0.082\textwidth, align=center, font=\bfseries]
    \tikzstyle{flower}  = [text width=0.082\textwidth, align=center, font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzstyle{type}    = [text width=0.082\textwidth, align=center, font=\tiny]

    \node [month] at (0.082*00\textwidth,3) {Janvier};
    \node [flower] at (0.082*00\textwidth,2) {Pin};
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0.082*00\textwidth,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.078\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0.082*11\textwidth,-12) {\includegraphics[width=0.078\textwidth]{example-image}};

    \node [type] at (0.082*11\textwidth,-14.005) {lumière \\ (phénix)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

cards:

```
\begin{center}
    \includestandalone[height=\textheight]{standalone}
\end{center}
```

You have to add `\usepackage{standalone}` to the preamble.

The result is the following:
[image: result]

If you don't want to have space at the left and right border, you have to change your tikzpicture to get a perfect fitting image.

Comment: Thank you very much.